# Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that $a^2$ is never a primitive root $\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across this question while studying primitive roots.  I know it has something to do with the fact that if the order of $a$ is $m$ then for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the order of $a^k$ is $m/(m,k)$.  The question is as follows:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that $a^2$ is never a primitive root $\pmod{p}$.

I would appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Comment: Okay. So, what would $m/\gcd(m,k)$ have to be for $a^2$ to be a primitive root?

Answer (score 3):

If $(a,p)=1$, then $1\equiv a^{p-1}=(a^2)^\frac{p-1}{2}$ implies that $\text{ord}_p(a^2)\le\frac{p-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ if and only if the order of $g$ modulo $p$ is $p-1$.

If the order of $a$ is not $p-1$, then $a^2$ has order less than or equal to the order of $a$, hence is not a primitive root.

If the order of $a$ *is* $p-1$ then what is the order of $a^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is correct: $\rm\:(m,k)>1\:\Rightarrow\:ord(a^k) = m/(m,k) < m = ord(a).\:$ Since $\rm\:a^k\:$ has smaller order than $\rm\:a,\:$  it doesn't have maximal order in $\rm\left<a\right>.\:$ Your problem is the special case $\rm\:2 = k\ |\ m$

Answer (score 0):

The order of $a^2$ is no more than $\frac{p-1}{2}$ since $a^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod{p}$ by [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).